# XORing two doubles in Java

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

How to XOR two doubles in JAVA?

simple '^' doesn't work for doubles... Would I have to convert a double to binary form and do it bitwise? or is there any other way?

Comment: Can't think of a nice way to do this, but I'm kind of curious about why you would want to do that in the first place... can you enlighten me?

Comment: Since XOR is a bitwise operator, it's usually applied only to integers. Do you really want to try to bitwise XOR doubles (which could lead to _really_ weird results) or do you just want to work with ints?

Comment: I am implementing a compression algorithm for a stream of doubles, and that algorithm requires XORing two consecutive numbers.

Comment: This might be useful simply for hashing purposes. But in that case be aware that comparisons to NaN are very unexpected in Java. They are always false.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you mean to do this bitwise you need to use the `Double` utility functions to get `long` representations and then convert back to a double at the end:

```
double c = Double.longBitsToDouble(
    Double.doubleToRawLongBits(a) ^ Double.doubleToRawLongBits(b));
```

Comment: Never convert the XOR-ed long back to double, because there are many bit patterns that lead to NaN, +infinity and -infinity and many other sets of bit patterns that represent the same number (one cacnonical, the rest denormal, the most common ones being +0 and -0, +0e1, +0e2, etc)