# Illegal Start of Expression Java Boolean?

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to run a Bitwise number comparison and my code keeps coming up with an Illegal start of expression on line 30 of my code with the "if" statement.

My code reads as so:

```
public class Project7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        double P = keyboard.nextDouble(); 
        double Q = keyboard.nextDouble();
        double R = keyboard.nextDouble();
        double S = keyboard.nextDouble();
        boolean First_Relation;
        boolean Second_Relation;

        if (P > Q) First_Relation = true;
        if (R < S) Second_Relation = true;

        if (First_Relation = true) & (Second_Relation = true); 
        System.out.println("Given the values for p,q,r, and s the expression "
        + "(p > q) && !(r < s) evaluates to " );
    }
}
```

Comment: `First_Relation = true` should be `First_Relation == true` in `if`

Comment: Why are people voting the question down? It states the issue as clearly as the asker is able, and demonstrates effort. Not every question has to be about advanced topics or target advanced coders.

Comment: You mean, the third if statement?

Comment: @shovavnik The question doesn't demonstarte effort on what did he try to solve the `syntactical error`, that is why.

Answer (score 104):

An `if` statement is of the form:

```
if (condition) statement
```

You've currently got *two* bracketed conditions... which also end up *assigning* values, which probably isn't what you want.

So first fix to get it to compile:

```
if ((First_Relation = true) & (Second_Relation = true))
```

Then change the assignments to equality checks, as otherwise it will simply assign `true` to both variables and the condition will pass regardless of their previous values:

```
if ((First_Relation == true) & (Second_Relation == true))
```

Then remove comparisons with boolean constants:

```
if ((First_Relation) & (Second_Relation))
```

Then remove unnecessary brackets:

```
if (First_Relation & Second_Relation)
```

Then make the variables follow Java naming conventions:

```
if (firstRelation & secondRelation)
```

Then use the more conventional `&&` instead of `&` - `&&` is short-circuiting, and is almost always what you want:

```
if (firstRelation && secondRelation)
```

Now you've still got a semi-colon directly after your `if` condition, which makes it pointless - it will *always* execute the `System.out.println` statement, because that's not part of the `if` statement. You *could* just remove the semi-colon, but I'd add braces for clarity:

```
if (firstRelation && secondRelation) {
    System.out.println("insert text here");
}
```

Next, note that you're only actually initializing your variables if the condition is true - so you'll currently get a compile-time error for trying to read variables which aren't definitely assigned.

First, fix the definite assignment:

```
// Names changed to follow conventions
boolean firstRelation = p > q;
boolean secondRelation = r < s;
```

... and the code above should be fine.

Next, spot that you're really gaining very little indeed from those extra variables. Inline the conditions instead:

```
if (p > q && r < s) {
    System.out.println("Given the values for p,q,r, and s the expression "
    + "(p > q) && !(r < s) evaluates to ";
}
```

At this point, it becomes very clear that there's a further bug - because your message talks about `!(r < s)` but the condition is just `r < s`. So you need to decide what you want to achieve, and make the code and the message reflect the same thing. Note that you don't finish the message, either. Indeed, you could simplify the whole thing to:

```
System.out.println("Given the values for p,q,r, and s the expression "
    + "(p > q) && !(r < s) evaluates to " + ((p > q) && !(r < s));
```

... or whatever you want the expression to actually be.

Comment: Nice answer! I'd also inline both relation expressions as they do enhance readability: if (P > Q && R < S) ...

Comment: @isnot2bad: True, will mention that.

Comment: @isnot2bad: Ouch, there was also a definite assignment issue, *and* the message was wrong. Yikes.

Comment: "So you need to decide what you want to achieve, and make the code ... reflect the same thing." The path to happiness lies this way.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, you can't use the `&` operator in Java to perform a *bitwise* comparison between *doubles*. It can only be used with other simpler primitives, like ints and chars.

In addition, the way you're using the `&` operator will not perform a bitwise comparison between the numbers because you're using it to compare the results of `P>Q` and `R<S`, both of which produce boolean values.

To perform a bitwise comparison between doubles, you need to use a different technique to directly compare P with Q and R with S. Here's an example of one way to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13928322/213343.

Comment: Where is he trying to perform bitwise comparison between doubles?

Comment: Not in the code. His question start with: "I'm trying to run a Bitwise number comparison...". My answer explains why his code is not accomplishing that goal. Plus, this fits with the incorrect usage of the & operator, which *is* the bitwise AND operator.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (First_Relation == true && Second_Relation == true)
{
    System.out.println("Given the values for p,q,r, and s the expression "
    + "(p > q) && !(r < s) evaluates to " );
}
```

and the Effective Way is

```
    if (First_Relation && Second_Relation)
    {
        System.out.println("Given the values for p,q,r, and s the expression "
        + "(p > q) && !(r < s) evaluates to " );
    }
```

Comment: The first snippet still won't compile, and you haven't really explained the differences.

Comment: Well that now compiles, but you haven't explained anything about why you've changed `&` to `&&` or `=` to `==`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to take

```
(First_Relation = true) & (Second_Relation = true)
```

into brackets.
And remove the ";" from the end of "if" statement, cause it makes no sense : ";" is considered as a new statement termination (empty statement in your case) and as you didnt provide the scope for "if" statement - it works only for the next statemnt i.e. empty statement.

Answer (score 1):

If the condition is not met then there's no message. I therefore suggest:

```
boolean evaluation = (P > Q) && !(R < S);
System.out.println("Given the values for p,q,r, and s the expression "
    + "(p > q) && !(r < s) evaluates to " + evaluation);
```