# How can I efficiently zero out the last 32 bits of a double in java?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit

How can I zero out the last 32 bits of a double, in java, as efficiently as possible?

Comment: Why would you want to zero out the last 32 bits of a double?

Comment: `(x>>32)<<32`  ?

Comment: You wouldn't want to this on a double since a double is encoded as a coefficient and an exponent. Doing a bitwise operation on a double isn't likely to give you the result you expect. Scaling to a float or converting the number to fixed point might work, depending on the value range.

Comment: You can always do  `a = Double.longBitsToDouble(Double.doubleToLongBits(a) & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000L);`

Comment: Ignore my last comment...this question should help you convert doubles to bits.  That way you can use some bit wise operators, then convert back to a double.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211095/xoring-two-doubles-in-java

Answer (score 7):

Try this.

```
private static final long ZERO_OUT_LAST_32_BITS = 0xffffffff00000000L;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double number = 2.5;

    long numberBits = Double.doubleToLongBits(number);
    double result = Double.longBitsToDouble(numberBits & ZERO_OUT_LAST_32_BITS);
}
```

It zeroes out the last 32 bits of the binary representation of your double by using a [binary AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_and#AND) operation.

However, make sure you know exactly what and why you are doing - I would at least expect an explaining comment next to code like this.

Answer (score 5):

Convert to long and mask away the desired bits, convert back:

```
long l = Double.doubleToLongBits();
l &= 0xFFFFFFFF00000000L;
double truncated = Double.longBitsToDouble(l);
```

Although I'm not sure what you're trying to achive by that...